What does Gödel mean by ‘class-signs’?
On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica and Related Systems, page 39:

A formula of PM with just one free variable, and that of the type of the natural numbers (class of classes), we shall designate a class-sign.

Why does he call “a formula with one free variable” a “class-sign”?

A sign as a basic unit of communication that conveys meaning can be anything that stands for something else, and in semiotics it's nothing but the perceived signifier and the conceived signified...

Because it "identifies" a class.

This question may be more suitable for math.stackexchange.com
